# Connect to online mysql database in eclipse

Tags: android, mysql, database, eclipse, database-connection

I'm creating an android app where I'm getting from an online mysql database. I'm rather new to this. I need to know how to connect to the database and then retrieve a specific row from the table using a variable in my code. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried already ? You can do that with a server-side language like PHP and retrieve your query results using JSON.

Try this link:

[Android - Connect to MySQL Database](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database)

Basically, this is a good option if you don't have any clue at when or how to start.

Comment: Thanks for the input Gil, isn't there an easier way for example using a DBConnect class etc. And I don't want to use php.